# MarkLogic: Get all documents from a collection via REST

Tags: rest, marklogic

Is it possible to get all documents from a specified collection in Marklogic via REST api?

Answer (score 5):

It should be possible to page over the documents with the [/v1/search](https://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/REST/GET/v1/search) endpoint by specifying an Accept header of `multipart/mixed; boundary="YOUR_BOUNDARY_HERE"` and the following query parameters:

- one or more `collection` parameters (or a POST payload with collection queries)
- a `view` parameter of `none`
- a `start` parameter for the offset to the next page of the result set

For more information see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search

Hoping that helps,